# android react-native-iap 12 requestPurchase

Tags: android, react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

I updated my app to "react-native": "0.72.4", and I use  "react-native-iap": "12.10.7". but requestPurchase function is not working correctly in android anymore.

```
******other codes*****
const purchaseRequest = createAsyncThunk(
    "somestring/somestring",
    async ({ skuID }: { skuID : string }, { dispatch }) => {
        try {
            if (Platform.OS == "ios") {
               await requestPurchase({ sku: skuID })
            } else {
               await requestPurchase({ skus: [skuID] }) 
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            devlog('Error occurred while making purchase',error)
        }
    }
)
******other codes*****
```

I read documentations but I couldn't find anything more than this answer and it's not working :
`requestPurchase(Platform.OS === 'ios' ? { sku } : { skus: [sku] });`

the error I get is :

```
{"code": "E_SERVICE_ERROR", "debugMessage": "", "message": "Billing is unavailable. This may be a problem with your device, or the Play Store may be down.", "responseCode": 3}
```

Comment: See it as well, have you found an answer?

Comment: I guess google changed some settings of accounts so previous payment test user accounts were not working even if we set country and other info correctly. Adding new accounts for test solved the problem.

Comment: For me it eventually was the problem that the products did not get loaded